# how to remove background img under the current page

Tags: jquery, html, css

below codes include two parts
the first one handle the #logo page only

```
$('#logo').on('click', function() {
// get home info
$.get('ajax.php', {page: 'home'}, function(data) {
    result = $.parseJSON(data);     
    // reset background
    $('#content-area').backstretch(result.background);      
    // reset navigation
    $('.current_page_item_green').removeClass('current_page_item_green');
    $('.current_page_item').removeClass('current_page_item');
    $('.nav-link').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('green');
    });     
    // fade out the footer
    $('#footer-row').fadeIn();      
    // reset copy
    $('#subnav').html('');
    $('#home-copy').html(result.copy);

    // reset sizes and colors
    $('#home-logo').animate({height: 200}, 0);
    $('#home-copy').animate({height: 200, backgroundColor: '#004329', color: 'white', paddingTop: 0}, 0);
});});
```

the second one handle the left pages ,

```
$(document).on('click', '.nav-link-ajax', function() { handleAjax($(this));});function handleAjax(eBtn) {
// get the page we want
getPage = eBtn.attr('href');        
// make AJAX call
$.get('ajax.php', {page: getPage}, function(data) {
    result = $.parseJSON(data);     
    // fill in new page
    $('#subnav').html(result.subnav);
    $('#home-copy').html(result.copy);

    // get document height and get rid of 15% minus the height of the boxes and padding
    docHeight = [$(document).height()-($(document).height()*.15)]-200;

    // change height of content boxes
    $('#home-logo').animate({height: docHeight}, 0);
    $('#home-copy').animate({height: docHeight, backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'gray', paddingTop: 0}, 0);

    // fade out the footer
    $('#footer-row').fadeOut();

    // change background
    $('#content-area').backstretch(result.background);

    // clear old nav
    $('.current_page_item_green').removeClass('current_page_item_green');
    $('.current_page_item').removeClass('current_page_item');

    // update navigation
    if (result.nav_color == 'green') {
        // add green
        $('.nav-link').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('green');
        });
        $(result.current_page_item).addClass('current_page_item_green');
    } else {
        $('.nav-link').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('green');
        });
        $(result.current_page_item).addClass('current_page_item');
    }
});}
```

My question is that  after clicking other webpage then go back to logo page, 
there are extra spaces on the bottom and on the right side 
it seems the logo page's background size will follow the background of the previous visited webpage.

how do I fix this issue?  thank you

Comment: you seem to be using a plugin or two as well. kinda hard to tell whats going on without a visual example. Could you give us a site link? Sandbox?

Comment: http://goo.gl/I5LVO here you go,  when you click this link, it will bring you to index.html , then you go to other tabs link then you will find what I mean  thank you

Comment: oh ouch, actually i'm noticing ALOT of background issues as I go through. For instance, if i click About first, then click again the background moves down first couple clicks, the more i click it, it stops moving and then starts getting bigger. And that's just one. I've reloaded the page several times and clicked different things each time, it does a half dozen different things (slide right, sometimes left, sometimes down, zooms infinatly on clicking). I'm not getting any console errors, but I think you're using that backsizer plug wrong. Honestly, why not just make a small change to your lay:

Comment: create a div just inside the body named background, set it to `position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: -999;` Put an img in it sized at 100%|100%. then simply change that image out on your ajax calls/page changes???

Comment: honestly, this was built from my previous coworker, I just got request from my client, so I need to go through this webpage then make a change.

Comment: it seems like  background setting is in ajax.php page, there is " $result['background'] = 'img/layout/bg_home.png';" inside, I guess this handle insert the background img.  so how do I create a div in body related to this command line?

Comment: If I were you, I'd completely remove the backstrech, html and calls in code. Then I would add something like: `<div id="background" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;z-index:-999;"><img alt="alt text not necessary" src="someImage.png" height="100%" width="100%"></div>` as the first element of the body. Then just change img (src or whole line) as needed. like: `$('#background img').attr("src", result.background);` ***GUARANTEED*** to work 100% of the time!

Comment: what you said is more clearly for me !! thanks.  but if I remove the backstrech, a lot of code will be changed ? thank you again?

Comment: From what I'm looking at, no. backstretch is only used to make the backgrounds. Now, I dont know how your HTML is laid out for each view, though, I assume, once you remove the backstretch code from your usage (not just the plugin of course), then all cases of it should disappear. It looks like it adds a `div#backstretch` everytime it's called. So i dont think any HTML would need to be changed. just find everywhere you see `.backstretch` and remove it, then apply my suggestion.

Comment: I'll make an answer and try to explain better.

Comment: hi SpYk3HH, I followed what u said, it works!!! but , I meet another issue that each webpage's background are the same!! it supposed to be different in each webpage. do you know why does it happend?

Comment: I just finished updating my answer, have you checked it yet?

Comment: it totally works!!!!!!! thank you very much !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Hi SpYk3HH,  there is an issue coming up,  my scroll bar does not work in some pages.  and it seems like after each clicking , home-copy.height will be added automatically. Could you help me to fix it ?thank you

Comment: I'm on the road, but when I get a chance, a look at it

Comment: sure thank you . I can create a new topic , just let me know !!! thank you very much

Comment: did you get this issue fixed? Sorry i'm so late getting back, but I'm looking through the pages now and not seeing the issue. If it's not fixed, could you maybe give me an example? With all these comments, this might need to be a new question (if you can formulate it in a way that doesn't get bashed, SO users getting fickle lately).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31331/discussion-between-han-and-spyk3hh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as I can see it, appears to be with the backstretch plugin. For one thing, it adds a new div element to the DOM *every time* it is called! That's just one of many issues I see with this plugin; sets position to `absolute` not fixed, doesn't account for parent position setting, etc.

My suggestion, remove it. Not just the plugin of course, but everywhere in your code that you're calling it. Simply use your IDE (Notepad++, Komodo Edit, etc...) to find all instances of `.backstretch(` and remove those lines. It looks like backstretch is adding this *background* div dynamically, so i don't think you'll need to remove any lines of HTML.

***FYI*** I found it called only 4 times in main.js and of course once in the plugins file

Lines [126, 152, 185, 237] in main.js

 Plugin exist in line 24 thru 28 of plugins.js

With that done, you should no longer have a background on any page. Double check, go ahead. I'll wait ...

Ok, ya back? No backgrounds but everything else is the same right? Checked console for errors? None? Good. Let's get this party started. The **easy** way to make a background is to use a div element of position `fixed`. Give it an inner img element and then simply change the source file as needed. Too easy right? Try this:

### HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="background" style="position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;z-index:-1;">
        <img alt="alt text not necessary" src="img/layout/bg_home.png" height="100%" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div ....
```

Then in your JS, replace that old line (the one you should have deleted by now) of `$('#content-area').backstretch(result.background);` with something more like:

For your initial setup on line 126 of main.js to:

```
$('#background img').attr("src", "img/layout/bg_home.png");
```

For lines [152, 185, 237]

```
$('#background img').attr("src", result.background);
```

Comment: I have other question about the scrollbar ,  do you accept I continue here or u prefer to the new topic?

Comment: Just FYI, it would probably be better to move that inline-style to a separate stylesheet. It's considered better form to keep your layout and your style separate.

Comment: @ColinDeClue Si si. I was gonna suggest, but for purpose of getting him on his way, I tried to just keep it simple.  Looks like he got it any way though. Good call! SO FOR ALL!